# SAS 9.3 connection to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sas

I am in a process to learn SAS using SQL server database (AdventureWorks). Would it be possible for someone to guide me through how to establish a connection so that I can get access to SQL server database. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome to begin trying (google SAS SQL Server), and come back with any questions you may have; but it is not appropriate to ask for a how-to guide on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

See this PDF from SAS Support:

http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts765.pdf

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC module.

Set up an odbc data source to SQL Server first.  Lets call it SASSQL123.
Then, assign a new SAS library (e.g. MyNewLib) with something like this:

```
libname MyNewLib odbc user=xxxxxxx pw=xxxxxxxx datasrc=SASSQL123 owner=dbo qualifier=XYZ; 
run;
```

(where qualifier is the database's name)